# Switching sass variables with angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, node-sass

I am working on theme changer with angularjs and I can't seem to find a way how to replace one sass file with another (both of them contains variables) when user changes his theme. I know that when sass is compiled to css the variables are gone. Is there a way to switch up those files and recompile whole css? I have managed to find that it should be somehow possible to do by calling server to recompile css, but I couldn't find more information. Thank you.

Comment: What information do you need? [Here](https://github.com/hashcc/SCSS-server-side-compiler) is a server side compiler. I think that can be done easily.

Comment: I am talking about angularjs, not php, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way we are doing these things is having multiple files for different themes. Example content =

```
variables ... 
primary: '#smtng'

.themeName{
   .header{
      background-color: primary
    }
}
```

And in your app.html you can add class to your html tag which will represent themeName. You can hold theme name in some storage and load it from there.

Basically you are loading all themes, but only rendering css for active theme

Comment: There are too many files scss files and duplication of them I don't really think is an option

Comment: Well that depends if you were thinking about theme at the beginning or if it was something you got to after couple of months of developing. It would actually be just couple of files where you will define variables. Then create some css class or selectors , example primaryColor, backgroundPrimaryColor etc. And its something like 30 lines of css per theme.